# insert href link above cboxPhoto in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am currently using the title: function to display two unique links and want to display one of the links directly above the cboxPhoto object or the cboxLoadedContent. any suggestions appreciated...

//Define the Title links

```
            $('a.aw14title').colorbox({title:function () {
            return "<div align='center' style='color:#000000; font-weight:bold;'>" +  $(this).data('image-link') +  "</div> <br><br> <span style='color:#000000; font-style:italic;'>*To download full set of Alienware 14 images,  " + "click HERE!".link("/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_ZIP&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware 14 Laptop.zip" + "</span>");
            }}); `enter code here`



 $(".aw14image").colorbox({rel:'aw14image', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%", scalePhotos: true, scrolling: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question and solution in this forum and modified the code to meet my needs. I now have  a link below the image using the title  and a link above the image using data-image-link. here is the code I used:

```
 $(".aw14image").colorbox({rel:'aw14image', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%" , scalePhotos: true, scrolling: false});
```

Next the title code for  the link below the image in the title box secion.

```
      $('a.aw14title').colorbox({title:function () {
            return "<span style='color:#000000; font-style:italic;'>To download full set of Alienware 14 images, </span> " + "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>click HERE! </span>".link("/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_ZIP&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware 14 Laptop.zip");
            }});
```

Last the piece was to use the oncomplete function to prependTo the cboxloadedcontent:

```
    $(".aw14image").colorbox({        
            onComplete:function(){ 
            $("<div align='center' style='color:#000000; font-weight:bold;'>" +  $(this).data('image-link') +  "</div>").prependTo("#cboxLoadedContent");
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML

```
    <a class="aw14image aw14title" data-image-link="<a href='/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_01&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware_14_Laptop/01.jpg' target='_blank'> Click HERE</a> to download & save product image"  href="productimages/Alienware_14_Laptop/01.jpg" >Alienware 14</a>
```